# Unit test redux toolkit queries connected via fixedCacheQuery using react testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have two components in my react app:

#### Component A

Performs a lazy fetch of users. This looks like:

```
const ComponentA = () => {
  const [trigger, {data}] = useLazyLoadUsers({
    fixedCacheKey: fixedLoadUsersKey,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    trigger();
  }, []);

  return <div>{data.map(user => user.id)}</div>
}
```

#### Component B

Wants to render a loading indicator while `useLazyLoadUsers`'s `isLoading` property equals `true`. This component looks like this:

```
const ComponentB = () => {
  const [, {isLoading}] = useLazyLoadUsers({
    fixedCacheKey: fixedLoadUsersKey,
  });

  if (!isLoading) {
    return <div>Users loaded</div>
  }

  return <div>Loading users</div>
}
```

#### The issue

While this works well (the states are in sync via the `fixedLoadUsersKey`), I'm struggling to find documentation or examples on how to test Component B.

Testing Component A is well documented here https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#ui-and-network-testing-tools.

I already have an overwritten react testing library `render` method that provides a real store (which includes all my auto-generated queries).

What I would like to do is testing that Component B loading indicator renders - or not - based on a mocked `isLoading` value. I want to keep my current or similar implementation, not duplicating the `isLoading` state into another slice.

So far, I have tried mocking `useLazyLoadUsers` without success. I also tried dispatching an initiator before rendering the test, something like

```
it('should render the loading indicator', async () => {
  const store = makeMockedStore();
  store.dispatch(myApi.endpoints.loadUsers.initiate());
  render(<ComponentB />, {store});
  expect(await screen.findByText('Loading users')).toBeVisible();
})
```

This didn't work either.

Does someone have a hint on how to proceed here or suggestions on best practices?